# How to use printers in dual-boot environment?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, printing, windows-10

How can I use printers that I am using with Windows 10 in Ubuntu that is installed on the same computer in dual-boot?

Comment: Install the printer on the network and not directly to your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot.
The only way to use a printer connected to a Windows machine would be via Samba. As you have Ubuntu and Windows on the same box (hence the term dual-boot), you cannot have both OS's running at the same time.
Thinking out loud: you could run Windows, install a VM product (VMware, VirtualBox) and create an Ubuntu VM.
That way you can have both OS's running at the same time and you can create the situation as mentioned above.

Comment: Or, just add the same printer devices under Ubuntu. There's almost certainly no need to talk to Windows to print to said physical printers.

Comment: @dobey: Depends on the printer. Some have no suitable Linux drivers.

Comment: @dobey how can I do that?

Comment: In the Printers under System Settings. @DavidFoerster Mac OS uses the same printing system as Ubuntu, and most every printer comes with appropriate PPDs for the Mac system, which can be used on Ubuntu. Most network printers do IPP now as well, and will be auto discovered. The "no suitable drivers" argument really doesn't hold up well these days.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Windows drivers in Ubuntu.

Most of printers have Linux drivers that you will need to install.

If you specify what are your printer models, it will be possible to suggest something regarding the drivers.